# Function for scaling numbers in a pd.DF with a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty new to Python. I'm trying to create a function which should look at a csv file, with an ID number, Name, and then N columns of numbers from different tests and then scale/round the numbers so they can be compared to the Danish grading system from [-3, 00, 02, 4, 7, 10, 12].

My script below does exactly that, but my function only returns the last result of the DF.

Here's the CSV, I use for testing:

```
StudentID,Name,Assignment1,Assignment2,Assignment3 
s123456,Michael Andersen,7,5,4 
s123789,Bettina Petersen,12,3,10 
s123468,Thomas Nielsen,-3,7,2 
s123579,Marie Hansen,10,12,12
s123579,Marie Hansen,10,12,12
s127848, Andreas Nielsen,2,2,2
s120799, Mads Westergaard,12,12,10
```

Its worth to mention that i need these functions separate, for my main script. 
I've made a simple function which loads the file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

def dataLoad(filename):
    grades = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return grades
```

then I've written this script for the rounding of the numbers:

```
# Importing modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Loading in the function dataLoad
from dataLoad import dataLoad

#Defining my data witht the function
grades=dataLoad('Karakterer.csv')
def roundGrade(grades):
    #Dropping the two first columns of the pd.DF
    grades=grades.drop(['StudentID','Name'],axis=1)
    #Making the pd.DF into a numpy array
    sample_grades=np.array(grades)
    #Setting the parameters of the scale to round up to
    grade_Scale = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
    #Defining i, so i get gradually bigger with each cycle
    i=0
    #Making a for loop, which rounds every number in every row of the given array
    for i in range(0,len(grades)):

        grouped = [min(grade_Scale,key=lambda x:abs(grade-x)) for grade in sample_grades[i,:]]
        #Making i 1 time bigger for each cycle
        i=i+1

    return grouped
```

Tell if you need some more information about the script, cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For improve performance use `numpy`:

```
#assign output to df instead grades for possible assign values back in last step
df = dataLoad('Karakterer.csv')
grades = df.drop(['StudentID','Name'],axis=1)

grade_Scale = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
grades=df.drop(['StudentID','Name'],axis=1)
print (grades)
   Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
0            7            5            4
1           12            3           10
2           -3            7            2
3           10           12           12
4           10           12           12
5            2            2            2
6           12           12           10

arr = grades.values
a = grade_Scale[np.argmin(np.abs(arr[:,:, None] - grade_Scale[None,:]), axis=2)]
print (a)
[[ 7  4  4]
 [12  2 10]
 [-3  7  2]
 [10 12 12]
 [10 12 12]
 [ 2  2  2]
 [12 12 10]]
```

Last if need assign back output to columns:

```
df[grades.columns] = a
print (df)
  StudentID               Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
0   s123456   Michael Andersen            7            4            4
1   s123789   Bettina Petersen           12            2           10
2   s123468     Thomas Nielsen           -3            7            2
3   s123579       Marie Hansen           10           12           12
4   s123579       Marie Hansen           10           12           12
5   s127848    Andreas Nielsen            2            2            2
6   s120799   Mads Westergaard           12           12           10
```

**Explanation**:

It is used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034583/2901002) but for multiple columns:

Idea is compare 2d array created from all columns from `DataFrame` to `arr` by array `grade_Scale`. So you can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for possible create `3d array` of differences between them with absolute values:

```
print (np.abs(arr[:,:, None] - grade_Scale[None,:]))

[[[10  7  5  3  0  3  5]
  [ 8  5  3  1  2  5  7]
  [ 7  4  2  0  3  6  8]]

 [[15 12 10  8  5  2  0]
  [ 6  3  1  1  4  7  9]
  [13 10  8  6  3  0  2]]

 [[ 0  3  5  7 10 13 15]
  [10  7  5  3  0  3  5]
  [ 5  2  0  2  5  8 10]]

 [[13 10  8  6  3  0  2]
  [15 12 10  8  5  2  0]
  [15 12 10  8  5  2  0]]

 [[13 10  8  6  3  0  2]
  [15 12 10  8  5  2  0]
  [15 12 10  8  5  2  0]]

 [[ 5  2  0  2  5  8 10]
  [ 5  2  0  2  5  8 10]
  [ 5  2  0  2  5  8 10]]

 [[15 12 10  8  5  2  0]
  [15 12 10  8  5  2  0]
  [13 10  8  6  3  0  2]]]
```

Then use position by minimal values by [`numpy.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) per `axis=2` (working with 3rd axis in 3d array):

```
print (np.argmin(np.abs(arr[:,:, None] - grade_Scale[None,:]), axis=2))
[[4 3 3]
 [6 2 5]
 [0 4 2]
 [5 6 6]
 [5 6 6]
 [2 2 2]
 [6 6 5]]
```

And last use indexing by `grade_Scale` values:

```
print (grade_Scale[np.argmin(np.abs(arr[:,:, None] - grade_Scale[None,:]), axis=2)])
[[ 7  4  4]
 [12  2 10]
 [-3  7  2]
 [10 12 12]
 [10 12 12]
 [ 2  2  2]
 [12 12 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-assigning the new calculated value to grouped in every iteration. One way to handle that is to declare a variable and append,

```
def roundGrade(grades):
    i = 0
    grouped = []
    for i in range(0,len(grades)):

        grouped.append([min(grade_Scale,key=lambda x:abs(grade-x)) for grade in sample_grades[i,:]])
        i=i+1
    return grouped
```

Now call the function,

```
roundGrade(np.array([[ 7,  5,  4],
   [12,  3, 10]]))

[[7, 4, 4], [12, 2, 10]]
```

Comment: Hi, that is wonderful, thank you. I was wondering if there is any way that I can make the same function but within the Pandas library? It might be easier to retain the syntax of Pandas throughout the script